# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo - LocationManager

Tags: android, localization, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to get the latitude and longitude for show my current location in the Google Map, but I'm getting this error:

```
03-04 18:00:50.785  13625-13625/com.example.thulio.googlemapstest W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e0c960)
03-04 18:00:50.785  13625-13625/com.example.thulio.googlemapstest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.thulio.googlemapstest/com.example.thulio.googlemapstest.MapPane}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.thulio.googlemapstest.MapPane.getCurrentLocation(MapPane.java:35)
            at com.example.thulio.googlemapstest.MapPane.onCreate(MapPane.java:28)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm just trying to get the current location one time and display on the Map.

MainActivity:

```
public class MapPane extends Activity{
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_pane);

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        getCurrentLocation();
    }


    public void getCurrentLocation(){
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        LatLng USER_LOCATION = new LatLng(longitude, latitude);

        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(USER_LOCATION, 13);
        map.animateCamera(update);

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(USER_LOCATION).title("USER LOCATION"));
    }
}
```

In the AndroidManifest:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
...
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: It is always good to put a form of comment next to the line that is causing the null pointer condition to narrow it down since the line numbers don't match up with what is posted.

Comment: @JaySnayder I think the problem is in the getLastKnowLocation(), but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you referenced the following snippet in your AndroidManifest.xml file as well?

```
<application ...>
   ...
   <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>
```

It is possible that this will return null if there is no currently known location or the provider is not currently available as noted within the [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)).  You should probably not rely on it being retrieve immediately but set it up such that you can check back on it when it is ready in your code.

Here is another [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) of someone setting up the manager and making an attempt within a try catch block.  Although feel free to do it in which ever means you would like.  But there isn't a guarantee that it will be ready right away.  Other checks need to be done.

Comment: Yes, the app works with a constant longitude and latitude, but when I try to get my current location I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/. This is a really nice tutorial for the same.